# Insert operation doesn't lock in typeorm (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, transactions, typeorm

I'm testing crud operations for the "SERIALIZABLE" isolation level in PostgreSQL with typeorm. And what I noticed, that update and delete operations are blocked with a proper error message ("could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions"). But when I use "insert" - it doesn't block another transaction fulfillment:

```js
app.get("/change-first", async function (_, res: Response) {
  const connection = getConnection();
  const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
  const { manager } = queryRunner;

  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction("SERIALIZABLE");

  try {
    const result = await manager.insert(User, { name: "Tom", account: 1000 });

    // const result = await manager.delete(User, { name: "Tom" });
    // const result = await manager.update(User, 2, { account: 2000 });

    await timer(4000);

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      res.json(err.message);
  } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
  }
});

app.get("/change-second", async function (_, res: Response) {
  const connection = getConnection();
  const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
  const { manager } = queryRunner;

  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction("SERIALIZABLE");

  try {
    const result = await manager.update(User, 1, { account: 1000 });

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      res.json(err.message);
  } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
  }
});
```

The same result I have with the setLock functionality. When I try (pessimistic_read or pessimistic_write) to block read/update/delete operations - all is good, but not for the insert one.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT and UPDATE do not violate serializability, so they don't need to get an error.

Logically, the UPDATE could have happened entirely first, and updated no rows as no rows with the condition exist.  Then the INSERT happened sequentially after the UPDATE, and also has no reason not to succeed.

Some of the other situations you allude to may also have a possible logically serial execution order.  But the serializable implementation doesn't guarantee to never have a false positive, but only not to have false negatives.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this does not seem to me to be a logical justification for such behavior. If I want to make it so that the data cannot be read in another transaction, I have to do something like this: ------ user = await em
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .setLock("pessimistic_write")
        .select("user")
        .from(User, "user")
        .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
        .getOne() ------ And then I can't read this row from another transaction.

Comment: The same if I use update or delete. But again, if I use insert, then it doesn't lock and I can read the data, even though it's being updated right now. It definitely works not as I expect... Delete and insert are similar operations, in my opinion, both change the data in a very common way. But the locking behavior though... And maybe getOne is not appropriate, to be clear. Better I used getMany() for this case.